# Finding a recursive formula for $r$ permute $n$

Tags: probability, combinatorics, solution-verification, recursion, fake-proofs

I'm learning about permutations, and have been playing around with them trying to find a recursive definition of $P(n+1,r)$ in terms of $P(n,r)$, where $P(n,r)$ represents the number of $r$ permutations of a set of $n$ elements.

My intuition is as follows:

$P(n+1,r) = (n+1)*P(n,r)$

Here is my "Proof":

Let $S$ be a set of $n+1$ elements. For each element $s_{i} \in S$, we have that $S-\{s_{i}\}$ has $n$ elements. Thus there are $P(n,r)$ r-permutations of the set $S-\{s_{i}\}$. There are $n+1$ choices for $s_{i}$, so there are $(n+1)*P(n,r)$ r-permutations in $S$.

This is clearly wrong. For example, $P(4,2) = 12 \not= 4*6 = 4*P(3,2)$

So where is my reasoning incorrect?

Comment: When you say there are $P(n, r)$ "such" permutations, permutations of what?

Comment: r-permutations of a set of n elements

Comment: And what relation does that have to the other calculations?

Comment: When I say "Thus there are (,) such permutations" I mean there are $P(n,r)$ such $r-permutations$ of the set $S-\{s_{i}\}$ since this set has $n$ elements.

Comment: Yes, and then how does that relate to the number of $r$-permutations of the set $S$?

Comment: To see where your reasoning is incorrect, it is best to examine the explicit formula for an r-permutation of n objects, which is: $\frac{n!}{(n-r)!}$. For n+1 objects, it is $\frac{(n+1)!}{(n-r+1)!}$. In other words, while you got the factor of $(n+1)$ right, you missed a factor of $(n-r+1)$ in the denominator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $P(n+1,r)$, you want to choose permutations of $r$ elements out of a set of $n+1$. In your reasoning, after choosing the first element ($n+1$ options), you have to choose only $r-1$ left. So you need $P(n,r-1)$ next rather than $P(n,r)$. Then the final answer is $(n+1)*P(n,r-1)$.

Comment: Thanks! This makes perfect sense